# Removing specific characters from a string from database select

Tags: php

I have stored data in cells like the following: `RP1=8, RP2=6, RP3=8, RP4=7` is there a ways that when I call that data to strip out the `RP1=` portion just leaving the value?

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['rp1'];
echo $row['rp2'];
echo $row['rp3'];
echo $row['rp4'];
```

print_r($row);

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [dashboardId] => 1 [memberId] => 1 [rp1] => RP1=8 [rp2] => RP2=6 [rp3] => RP3=8 [rp4] => RP4=7 [teamId] => 1 )
```

Comment: `$row['rp1']` actually, there's no column `rp1` , right?

Comment: show `print_r($row);`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I get this: `Array ( [id] => 1 [dashboardId] => 1 [memberId] => 1 [rp1] => RP1=8 [rp2] => RP2=6 [rp3] => RP3=8 [rp4] => RP4=7 [teamId] => 1 )`

Comment: You should clean-up your values in the database itself; remove the column names from them.

Comment: @jeroen during the submission of the data? Unfortunately I didn't put that part together I am working with the output however I have suggested this.

Comment: I guess you're lucky that the id isn't stored as `id=1` then ;-)

Comment: I am lucky, it could have been a  nightmare, I would have refused to work on it

Comment: Do this `print preg_replace('#(RP[0-9]+=)#','','RP8=2');` like `print preg_replace('#(RP[0-9]+=)#','',$row['rp1']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to rome:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
#replace can go over all entries here, it is specific enuff
$row = array_map(function($a){return preg_replace('#^(RP[0-9]+=)#','',trim($a));},$row);
echo $row['rp1'];
echo $row['rp2'];
echo $row['rp3'];
echo $row['rp4'];
```